# Is there a way to create "Search Suggestions" interface with UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

In my app, I need to create a Search Suggestions interface -- very similar to  Google search (it starts displaying suggestions as you type in the search field).

I did it with a `UISearchController` with the search bar in navigation bar, set it up like this:

```
// setup search controller
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchSuggestionsController)
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchSuggestionsController
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar

// ISSUE!! definesPresentationContext needs to be false or I can't push this
// controller multiple times on the navigation stack
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

while it works fine when search controller is pushed to the navigation stack the first time, it doesn't let the search bar get the focus when it is pushed the second time, as shown below

[image: with definesPresentationContext = true, it doesn't let search bar get focus the second time I push search controller on to the navigation stack]

but if I set it to false: as soon as I start typing into the search bar, the navigation bar (along with the search bar) disappears. This is expected behavior since (because of `definesPresentationContext = false`) `UISearchController` is now trying to display its view on top of `UINavigationController`'s view, as shown below:

[image: with definesPresentationContext = false, navigation bar disappears as soon as I start typing]

Is there a way to achieve this through UISearchController? If not, any pointers on how should I create a custom control for this? (Code for the minimal app shown in the animations can be [downloaded here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6845322/SearchBarIssue2.zip))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use UISearchController like this. UISearchBar and UINavigationBar are known to not play well together. What I decided to do was, every time user taps the Search button, I check `childViewControllers` array of my navigation controller and if I find an instance of `SearchViewController` in there, I pop back to it. Otherwise I push it.

```
// This function lives inside a UINavigationController subclass and is called whenever I need to display the search controller
func search() {
    if let _ = self.topViewController as? SearchViewController {
        return
    }

    var existingSearchController: SearchViewController? = nil
    for childController in self.childViewControllers {
        if let searchController = childController as? SearchViewController {
            existingSearchController = searchController
        }
    }

    if let searchController = existingSearchController {
        self.popToViewController(searchController, animated: true)
        return
    }

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(StoryboardConstants.SegueShowSearchController, sender: nil)
}
```

The proper fix would have been, of course, a custom control but we did not have the time to write something custom at this stage.